# Is there an "escape velocity" for closed dimensions?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime-dimensions, escape-velocity

Assuming a closed universe, the shape of the universe is often considered, or at least presented in pop science, to be a glome (4-sphere), and popularly depicted as behaving analogously to a 3-sphere, but in higher dimensions. This is, to my understanding, no different in kind, only in degree, to the curvature of space that characterizes a gravity well (i.e. it determines the geodesics).

Likewise, assuming spatial dimensions beyond the "big three" x, y, z, they are considered in the theories that posit them to be "small", that is, to my understanding, they curve back on themselves, analogously to x, y, z curving back on themselves in a closed universe, except the small extra dimensions do so at much shorter distances.

Now, given the above example of a closed universe being presented in popular science as a higher-dimensional analogue to a sphere, and under the assumption that spatial curvature that characterizes gravity wells is no different in kind from spatial curvature that characterizes a 4-sphere, or curled-up small extra dimensions, I'm lead to believe that both of these types of spatial curvature can be overcome by an escape velocity at least in theory, just like gravity wells can.

Is this idea correct? If so, what would that escape velocity be? Is it incorrect? If so, what differentiates this from a gravity well?

Answer (score 2):

No, this theory is not correct. There are two reasons.

One is that the geometry of a gravity well is not comparable to the geometry of a closed universe. Gravity wells have decreasing curvature as one moves away from the body, and this is why there is an escape velocity: at some speed most trajectories are unbound and can go off to infinity. But a constant curvature space has the same curvature everywhere. However, trajectories there also go arbitrarily far (eventually returning to the origin if it is positive curvature) even for a small speed.

The second, and more important, reason is that you cannot accelerate away from a spacetime manifold. You may think there is an embedding space outside the manifold, but this is not part of the theory. The theory clearly says that any forces and interactions you have on the manifold only act "along" it: you don't get any force or acceleration that makes a particle fly away from the manifold. It is a bit like trying to get a particle subjected to forces only in the x-y plane to gain velocity along the z-direction. It is literally mathematically impossible in a well-posed theory like general relativity (and made even more impossible by the lack of given embedding space in the theory).